# Does Near Future Propulsion (KSP mod) get easier late game?

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program

After playing Kerbal Space Program way too much. I added the mod "Near Future Propulsion" along with the axillary near future mods.

[image: Near Future Propulsion]

But now, mid-career it looks like the nuclear engine (everyone's go-to engine) is totally nerfed and useless.

My question is: does Near Future make the game easier late game? Are there good engines coming? Or did NFP just nerf everything?

Comment: I have not used this mod yet, but I assume you mean the stock nuclear engine was nerfed?

Comment: @Josh Yes, I'm talking about the stock nuclear engine. What was the second best engine in the game. And is now totally nerfed.

Comment: @Coomie define "second best". Every engine has its pros and cons and is useful for different situations. The LV-N is and always was a niche engine with really bad thrust-to-weight ratio and really good fuel efficiency. That makes it great for interplanetary transfer burns but quite useless when you need to accelerate quickly, like starts and landings.

Comment: @Philipp Sure each engine has it's benefits but after the initial heavy lift (which can be done with almost anything) there are only 2 engines you'll ever need: the Rockmax 48-7S and the LV-N. The LV-N (nuclear) for interplanetary/orbital insertion burns, and the 48-7S for dropships. In a pinch the 48-7S can be used for interplanetary burns where the LV-N shouldn't be used in dropships because of it's massive weight. That makes the LV-N possibly the 2nd best engine in the game IMHO.

Comment: When people complain about the performance of the nuclear engine, it usually turns out that they're using standard LF/O fuel tanks, and have forgotten to remove the oxidizer.  Is this the case in your situation?